# Hypergeometric Distribution over an interval

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

In a village with 2000 people, 100 people suffer from Alzheimer's disease. On a certain day, 40 people are admitted to a hospital.

**Calculate the probability that between $15$ and $25$ people (inclusive) of the patients admitted have Alzheimer's disease.**

My attempt:

Let $X$ be the patients admitted who have Alzheimer's disease. 
N = 2000, n = 40, m = 100
$$P(15 \leq x \leq 25) = P(X=25) - P(X=15) = \frac{\binom{100}{25} \binom{1900}{15}}{\binom{2000}{40}}-\frac{\binom{100}{15} \binom{1900}{25}}{\binom{2000}{40}} $$

**What is the expected number of patients who have Alzheimer's disease?**

$$ E(X) = 40 \frac{100}{2000} =2$$

Is this right?

Comment: Are you assuming that individuals with and without Alzheimer's are equally to be admitted to the hospital?

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is true, Hypergeometric Distribution has mean $n\frac{m}{N}$, based on your definitions. Also, it is very intuitive, i.e. if we have $\frac{m}{N}$ Alzheimer in our population, a small sample will also reflect that.

But, $P(a \leq x \leq b) = P(x \leq b) - P(x \lt a)$ in general. Not the way you wrote. So, your probability will be

$$P(15 \leq x \leq 25)=\sum_{n=15}^{25} \frac{\binom{100}{n}\binom{1900}{40-n}}{\binom{2000}{40}}$$

Unfortunately, the CDF of hypergeometric distribution is not easy in closed form. Please check [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hypergeometric_distribution). That's why I left it in summation form. However, you can employ several approximations if you really need a numerical value, but it'll be extremely close to 0 since your mean is 2, and (if you calculate) your variance is low. We're trying to find the probability of a very unusual event.